# Python-chess: module 'chess.engine' has no attribute 'SimpleEngine'

Tags: python, python-chess

This is part of a larger project, but I created a new file to solve this one problem. Sorry, I am still new to coding. Currently, I am trying to get stockfish evaluations for positions in Chess, however whenever I try to run the code, I get "AttributeError: module 'chess.engine' has no attribute 'SimpleEngine'" I have looked over the internet and can't find anything, am I being dumb? I tried the code from the documentation as well, and I still get the same error. This is the code from the documentation:

```
!pip install python-chess
!pip install stockfish
import chess
import chess.engine
from stockfish import Stockfish
import asyncio

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("stockfish")

board = chess.Board()
while not board.is_game_over():
    result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.100))
    board.push(result.move)

engine.quit()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-5ab68cc48dde> in <module>()
      4 import asyncio
      5 
----> 6 engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("stockfish")
      7 
      8 board = chess.Board()

AttributeError: module 'chess.engine' has no attribute 'SimpleEngine'
```

Comment: Could you please run the command `pip show python-chess` and show output?

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev

`Name: python-chess
Version: 0.23.11
Summary: A pure Python chess library with move generation and validation, Polyglot opening book probing, PGN reading and writing, Gaviota tablebase probing, Syzygy tablebase probing and XBoard/UCI engine communication.
Home-page: https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess
Author: Niklas Fiekas
Author-email: niklas.fiekas@backscattering.de
License: GPL3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use an outdated version of the `python-chess` package. Your current version is `0.23.11` while the latest version is `1.999`.

You should try to upgrade your package:

```
pip install python-chess --upgrade
```